# Is there any other way besides using the method of modifying the xml file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, config

I'm having trouble modifying App.Config

I added an App.Config file to the project, and now I want to modify the value of a node in the file. But it seems that I can only modify the app.Config in the Debug folder using this method, but what I want to modify is the project folder Under the App.Config file.

```
Configuration cfa = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
cfa.AppSettings.Settings.Remove(nodeName);
cfa.AppSettings.Settings.Add(nodeName, value);
cfa.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

Is there any other way besides using the method of modifying the xml file?

Comment: The app.config in the root of the project is intended to be the "template" from which an appropriate config file will be generated during build. Your code wouldn't generally have access to any aspect of the project system at *runtime*. Hint: it would help a lot if you could describe the *problem* to which you *thought* that part of the solution was modifying this specific file.

Comment: You need to make sure your config file is in the relative path of the executable, so that it can be achieved through code.

Comment: I'm sure, my code is given. I just want to know what is wrong with my code? Or how to implement it with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you confirm, you can try the following code. This ensures access to your App.Config.

```
    ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();   
    fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = @”\\..\\..\\app..config”;    // relative path names possible
    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap,ConfigurationUserLevel.None);   // Open another config file
```